# Deserialize TimeZone dentro de um JObject

Tags: c#, json, .net, timezone

Tenho tentado Deserializar um JObject para não transformar o timezone que recebo em uma resposta. Porém dessa forma o "DateTimeZoneHandling.Unspecified" não surte efeito e ainda sim o TimeZone -03:00 é transformado para +00:00 e a hora muda

```
var response = context.Response.Body.As<String>(preserveContent: true);
var result   = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(
    response,
    new JsonSerializerSettings {
        DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Unspecified 
    }
);
return result["result"].ToString();
```

No fim eu sou obrigado a retornar como string.

Answer (score -2):

Utilize apenas

```
new JsonSerializerSettings {
       DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset
}
```

Voce definindo `DateTimeZoneHandling.Unspecified`, voce esta dizendo para converter para horario local se a string tiver uma time zone definida.